# Is it possible to return HTML with AWS API Gateway using the "HTTP" protocol (not REST)?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to return HTML with AWS API Gateway using the "HTTP API" protocol?

I have a lambda python function to return some HTML.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML from HTTP API Gateway/Lambda</title></head>' 
    html += '<body><h1>HTML from HTTP API Gateway/Lambda</h1></body></html>'
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': html
    }
```

The HTTP API Gateway is set up as default.

The result in the browser is the HTML not interpreted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML from HTTP API Gateway/Lambda</title></head><body><h1>HTML from HTTP API Gateway/Lambda</h1></body></html>
```

I assume it has to do with the header "Content-type" which shows up as "text/plain" but I can't seem to find where to change this, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do with **HTTP API** as well, I just added header in the lambda response like below:

```
    import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML from HTTP API Gateway/Lambda</title></head>' 
    html += '<body><h1>HTML from HTTP API Gateway/Lambda</h1></body></html>'
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': html,
        "headers": {"Content-type": "text/html"}
    }
```

[image]

There is more information how you can handle your responses directly from your lambda [Working with AWS Lambda proxy integrations for HTTP APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html)

Comment: That worked. Great simple solution to something that was taking a lot of time trying to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: glad I was able to help!